# Android SSL issues

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am having problems in connecting server using ssl from android emulater. I have created public key using portecle(bks).When i used to connect server,authentication is not taking place.Logcat is not showing any error but ssl connection is not working.

My Source Code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory; 
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager;
import com.myclinicmyway.*;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

 public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

   public final Context context;


  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
  //"http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {

    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);

  }// end of client connection


  private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {

    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
      InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.docinbangalorefinals);

      try {
        trusted.load(in, "docinbangalore".toCharArray());
      } finally {
        in.close();    
      }
      return new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }// end of catch

  }// end of ssl socket

}// end of clas
```

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? What do you see happening at the place that you check? A regular http connection? (you do have a "https://" url in your code?)

Comment: if i used http i m getting response from servlet

Comment: What exactly happens when you do a https connection? Is there an attempt to connect, is the authentication failing, ...? Solving problems gets much simpler if you know the reason. And if you don't find any log then take e.g. [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and look at the raw connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.Following code worked for me.

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {
final Context context;
TrustManager easyTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(
            X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }    
};
  public MyHttpClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(
        new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }


  private MySSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");      
      try {
         trusted.load(null, null);

      } finally {
      }

      MySSLSocketFactory sslfactory =  new MySSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        sslfactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sslfactory;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new AssertionError(e);
    }

  }
  public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
    }
   }
```